# after click on submit button URL change How to keep it as it is without changes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-7.0

I work on an ASP.NET MVC razor page. I face issue Url change from

```
Resignation/RequesterIndex?filenumber=103085
```

to

```
Resignation/Create
```

after click submit button.

I need URL as it was before, without change after click submit button. How to do that please?

What is issue on my code that make this issue?

My code details as below

```
@model HR.WorkforceRequisition.Models.ResignationRequester

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Requester Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Resignation", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "ResignationForm", style = "padding-top: 50px" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.errorMsg))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            @ViewBag.errorMsg
        </div>
    }

    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.successMessage))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            @ViewBag.successMessage
        </div>
    }

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dept, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dept, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dept, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Designation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Designation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Designation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResignationSubmissionDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResignationSubmissionDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResignationSubmissionDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <span class="text-danger"> *</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}




  public class ResignationController : Controller
    {

        #region Requester Actions
        // GET: Resignation
        public ActionResult RequesterIndex(string filenumber)
        {
            int maxRequest = 0;
            string userRole = "";
            ResignationRequester resignationRequester = new ResignationRequester();
            int employeeFileNo;
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filenumber))
            {
               
              
                if (int.TryParse(filenumber, out employeeFileNo))
                {
                    JDEUtility jde = new JDEUtility();
                    userRole = Workforce.GetUserRole(employeeFileNo);
             
                    
                    var EmpName = jde.GetEmployeeDetailsForResignation(employeeFileNo);
                    if (EmpName.Count==0)
                    {
                        // ViewBag.errorMsg = "No Data For This File No";
                        return RedirectToAction("UnauthorizedUser", "Home", null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Session[SessionKeys.UserCode] = resignationRequester.EmpID = employeeFileNo;
                        Session[SessionKeys.Username] = resignationRequester.EmpName = EmpName[0];
                        Session[SessionKeys.Department] = resignationRequester.Dept = EmpName[3];
                        Session[SessionKeys.Designation] = resignationRequester.Designation = EmpName[4];
              
                        resignationRequester.EmpID = employeeFileNo;
                        resignationRequester.EmpName = EmpName[0];
                        resignationRequester.MobileNo = EmpName[5];
                        Session[SessionKeys.DepartmentCode] = EmpName[6];
            
                        resignationRequester.ResignationSubmissionDate = DateTime.Now;
                        resignationRequester.Designation = EmpName[4];
                        Session[SessionKeys.NoticePeriod] = Convert.ToInt32(EmpName[2]);
                        resignationRequester.LastWorkingDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(Convert.ToInt32(EmpName[2]));
                        Session[SessionKeys.SubmitionDate] = resignationRequester.ResignationSubmissionDate;
                        Session[SessionKeys.LastWorkingDate] = resignationRequester.LastWorkingDate;
                    }
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.errorMsg = "incorrect file no";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.errorMsg = "unauthorized user";
            }
            return View(resignationRequester);
        }
       
       
        
      
        

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RequesterIndex(ResignationRequester resignationRequester)
        {
          
            var filenumber = resignationRequester.EmpID;
            if (Session[SessionKeys.UserCode] != null)
            {
                resignationRequester.DeptCode = Session[SessionKeys.DepartmentCode].ToString();
                resignationRequester.EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(Session[SessionKeys.UserCode]);
                resignationRequester.EmpName = Convert.ToString(Session[SessionKeys.Username]);
                resignationRequester.Dept = Convert.ToString(Session[SessionKeys.Department]);
                resignationRequester.Designation = Convert.ToString(Session[SessionKeys.Designation]);
                int noticeperiod = Convert.ToInt32(Session[SessionKeys.NoticePeriod]);
                int julianRequestDate = 0;// JulianDate.DateTimeToJulian(resignationRequester.LastWorkingDate);
                int SubmitionDate = 0; //JulianDate.DateTimeToJulian((DateTime)Session[SessionKeys.SubmitionDate]);
                JDEUtility jde = new JDEUtility();


                var propertiesWithErrors = ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Any())
                                             .Select(x => x.Key)
                                             .ToList();
                //  Workforce.InsertToReignation(resignationRequester, (string)Session[SessionKeys.Username],(DateTime)Session[SessionKeys.LastWorkingDate], noticeperiod, (int)Session[SessionKeys.UserCode]);
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (resignationRequester.DirectManager == 0)
                    {
                        ViewBag.errorMsg = "Department Manager Must Be Bigger Than 0";
                        goto InvalidModel;
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.LineManager).Length < 6 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(resignationRequester.LineManager.ToString()))
                    {
                        ViewBag.errorMsg = "Length Line Manager Must Be equal 6 or More";
                        goto InvalidModel;
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.DirectManager).Length < 6 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(resignationRequester.DirectManager.ToString()))
                    {
                        ViewBag.errorMsg = "Length Direct Manager Must Be equal 6 or More";
                        goto InvalidModel;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.LineManager)) && resignationRequester.LineManagerName == null)
                    {
                        ViewBag.errorMsg = "Line Manager Name Blank";
                        goto InvalidModel;
                    }
                    if (julianRequestDate > 0 && SubmitionDate > 0 && julianRequestDate < SubmitionDate)
                    {
                        ViewBag.errorMsg = "Last Worked Date Must be Bigger than Submit Date";
                        goto InvalidModel;
                    }
                  
                    int checkEmployeeNoExist = jde.CheckEmployeeExistOrNot(resignationRequester.EmpID);
                    if (checkEmployeeNoExist >= 1)
                    {
                        ViewBag.errorMsg = "Employee Exist Before";
                        goto InvalidModel;
                    }

                  
                    try
                    {
                        Workforce.InsertToReignation(resignationRequester, (string)Session[SessionKeys.Username], (DateTime)Session[SessionKeys.LastWorkingDate], noticeperiod, (int)Session[SessionKeys.UserCode]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ViewBag.errorMsg = "Create Not Done Correctly";
                    }
                    Session[SessionKeys.DirectManager] = GetEmployeeName(Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.DirectManager));
                    Session[SessionKeys.LineManager] = GetEmployeeName(Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.LineManager));
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.errorMsg))
                    {
                        ViewBag.successMessage = "Resignation Submission form Created successfully";
                    }

                 
                }
                else
                {
                    var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
                                            .Where(y => y.Count > 0)
                                            .ToList();
                    ViewBag.errorMsg = "Some Required Fields Not Added";
                    goto InvalidModel;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.errorMsg = "No Data For This File No";
            }
        InvalidModel:
            ViewBag.isPostBack = true;
                return View(resignationRequester);
           // return RedirectToAction("RequesterIndex", new { filenumber = resignationRequester.EmpID });
        }
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id, string msg)
        {

            ViewBag.msg = msg;
            ViewBag.AllowDelete = false;
            ViewBag.AllowApprove = true;
          
   
            ResignationRequester workforceRequest = Workforce.ResignationGetRequestByID((int)id);
            
         

       
          
           
           
          


           

            return View(workforceRequest);
        }


     




        
    }
}
```

on requestindexer.cshtml

```
 $("#ResignationApp").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

                // Serialize the form data
                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                console.log("data is" + formData)
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    /* url: "/Resignation/RequesterIndex", // Replace with your actual URL*/
                    url: '@Url.Action("RequesterIndex", "Resignation")',
                   data: formData,
               /*     data: JSON.stringify(formData),*/
         /*           contentType: "application/json",*/

                //            headers: {
                //    RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                //},
                    success: function (response) {
                        // Handle the success response here
                        $("#successMessage").show();
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        // Handle any errors here
                        console.error(error);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Model ResignationRequester:

```
public class ResignationRequester
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dept./ Branch: ")]
    public string Dept { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Designation: ")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Resignation Submission Date: ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ResignationSubmissionDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile No: ")]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

**Updated post**

sample code on answer below is working correctly and make ajax

request to api and action

but validation notation not working

so How to solve this issue

I will assume that Resignation is controller and action and view is for

RequesterIndex and no need create because this issue happen on same

controller action

after investigate I remove

```
e.preventDefault();
```

validation display

so how to display validation and on same time not change URL

Comment: so what I do to solve this issue can you give me more details by modify code above

Comment: ok good can you please share with me source code i can give me any details you need

Comment: You should change `Html.BeginForm("Create",` to `Html.BeginForm("FunctionYouWantToAccess"`. This will auto route to that function

Comment: how to do that can you show me please

Comment: Can you edit you question to include the function inside the `ResignationController` you are trying to Post this request to? That way we can diagnose what is actually happening. I assume your function is called `RequesterIndex` based on the afore mentioned Route you want

Comment: I updated post so can you check please

Comment: after investigate I remove 

    e.preventDefault();

validation display

so how to display validation and on same time not change URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code specifies that the form should be posted to the "Create" action of the "Resignation" controller. That's why you see the URL change to "Resignation/Create" after submitting the form.

You can use AJAX to submit a form without causing a page refresh

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Include jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <!-- Your form fields here -->
        <input type="text" name="Dept" id="Dept">
        <input type="text" name="Designation" id="Designation">
        <!-- Add other form fields as needed -->
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Display success message here -->
    <div id="successMessage" style="display: none;">
        Form submitted successfully!
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

                // Serialize the form data
                var formData = $(this).serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Resignation/Create", // Replace with your actual URL
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        // Handle the success response here
                        $("#successMessage").show();
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        // Handle any errors here
                        console.error(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what I do to solve this issue can you give me more details by modify code above

Comment: You can use JavaScript and AJAX to submit the form asynchronously without causing a page refresh. This way, the URL will not change, and you can update the page content as needed. Jquery included in your project? I can share an example code.

Comment: ok good can you please share with me source code i can give me any details you need

Comment: after investigate I remove 

    e.preventDefault();

validation display

so how to display validation and on same time not change URL